# Different views to list users in postgresql 9.5

Tags: postgresql

Somebody could tell me the difference between the views pg_users, users and \du+ command to display users in Postgresql 9.5.

```
select * 
from users
```

display users that are not in pg_user views

Answer (score 1):

"users" is not a catalog table - it is yours. to check waht happens when you use meta-command in `psql` - use `-E` switch, eg:

```
~]$ psql t -E
Timing is on.
psql (9.5.4)
Type "help" for help.

t=# \du+
********* QUERY **********
SELECT r.rolname, r.rolsuper, r.rolinherit,
  r.rolcreaterole, r.rolcreatedb, r.rolcanlogin,
  r.rolconnlimit, r.rolvaliduntil,
  ARRAY(SELECT b.rolname
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_auth_members m
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_roles b ON (m.roleid = b.oid)
        WHERE m.member = r.oid) as memberof
, pg_catalog.shobj_description(r.oid, 'pg_authid') AS description
, r.rolreplication
, r.rolbypassrls
FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles r
ORDER BY 1;
**************************

                                                                                       List of roles
    Role name     |                         Attributes                         |  Member of  |                                         Description
------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 vao          |                                                            | {}          |
```

If you dig further you will find out that in 9.5 at least both `pg_user` and `pg_roles` query from `pg_authid`